# How does key extraction work with the Java Comparator.comparing() method?

Tags: java, interface, comparator, comparable, method-reference

The Java API specifies the following for the comparing() method in the Comparator<T> interface:

```
static <T,​U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing (Function<? super T,​? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

> Accepts a function that extracts a Comparable sort key from a type T,
> and returns a Comparator that compares by that sort key. The
> returned comparator is serializable if the specified function is also
> serializable.
>
> For example, to obtain a Comparator that compares Person objects by
> their last name,
>
> ```
>  Comparator<Person> byLastName = Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName);
> ```

My question is, what happens when this Comparator's <T>compare(T t1, T t2) method is invoked? For example, suppose `persons` is a List<Person> and is sorted using the comparator previously defined above:

```java
Collections.sort(persons, byLastName);
```

Assuming `getLastName` returns a String, which implements `Comparable<String>`, how exactly does `byLastName` compare the keys extracted by `getLastName`? Does the comparator implicitly invoke something like `return t1.getLastName().compareTo(t2.getLastName())`?

Comment: How about just look at [how it is implemented in the OpenJDK](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Comparator.java#L464)?

Comment: Thanks, that did not occur to me. Likewise, it did not occur to me that a functional interface could be used as a return type, and thus a lambda expression could occur in a return statement. It's weird to see because I think of lambdas as anonymous classes that you pass to a method's parameters directly as an argument.